# Ruby: Print something x amount of times

Tags: ruby, string, return, append

I want to return a string 'x' amount of times. My current code

```
return str + str + str + str
```

What do I do to make it look something like

```
return 4 * str
```

Comment: You are poisoned by inaccurate use/understanding of multiplication as is often seen in English speaking countries. A x B means A is repeated B times, not B repeated A times. It is by commutativity of multiplication that you can use them interchangeably. But they mean different. Here, you are seeing one case where the difference matters. 4 repeated str many times does not make sense. str repeated 4 times is what you want.

Comment: If your code is the last line in a method, you don't need to use `return`. Ruby automatically uses the last value seen as the return value from a method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close...

```
return str * 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
4.times{puts string}
```

Answer (score 0):

String*integer gives you a new String containing integer copies of the receiver, and also integer must be equal or greater than 0.
For Example-->
"Hello World!"*3 ==> "Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!"

Reference
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html